# Disable cursor(current) line highlight for vim + tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm using tmux + vim. Unlike vim split window, whenever I move focus to a different pane in tmux, the line highlight does not turn off like the following picture.

[image: Vim in two panes have line highlight]
The red lines are the cursor lines and I moved the focus to the bottom tmux pane but the top pane vim cursor line still has highlight.

I would like to turn off the cursor line highlight when I leave the pane in tmux and only have highlight line for the current tmux pane. 
Does anyone know how to do that?

My vim setting for the line highlight is

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Cursor line highlight
hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred 
hi CursorColumn cterm=NONE ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred 
" hlight current line current window only
augroup CursorLine
    au!
    au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
    au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

====== EDIT 1 ======

```
au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter,FocusGained,CmdwinEnter * setlocal cursorline
au WinLeave,FocusLost,CmdwinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
```

Also doesn't work.

====================

Comment: Do you get `FocusLost,FocusGained` events inside tmux? You could then use those.

Comment: Being single-threaded and running in a separate shell makes it impossible for the top session to know that you left it for another one so it sounds like a *very* non-trivial task. Why don't you simply use Vim's windows?

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I tried FocusLost,Gained. But inside the tux, vim thinks that it grabs the focus all time.

Comment: @romainl, I want to run several terminal program while editing the source code. i.e. I edit python scripts and on different tmux pane, I debug them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using iTerm2 you can use [sjl/vitality.vim](https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim) plugin which should work(ie restore `FocusLost`/`FocusGained` functionality) out of the box (according to the README, I can't try it out).

The [akracun/vitality.vim](https://github.com/akracun/vitality.vim) fork provides the functionality for other terminals (xterm/uxterm according to the commit logs, though it works flawlessly on gnome-term for me).

Starting from tmux 1.9a  you'll need to :

- add `set -g focus-events on` to your .tmux.conf
- add `let g:vitality_tmux_can_focus = 1` to your .vimrc

Then

```
au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter,FocusGained,CmdwinEnter * setlocal cursorline
au WinLeave,FocusLost,CmdwinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
```

should work as expected